# Re-writing MySQl query for execute faster

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, mysql

Can any one re-write this SQL query to perform better?

At present this query takes about 29 seconds to execute in **BlueHost** server while it takes 6 seconds in **HostGator**.com server.

My intention is to delete all records exists in **wp_postmeta** table of post type=**'attachment'** and with meta_key='_**mycbgenie_managed_by**
'

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN 
( SELECT ID FROM wp_posts 
    WHERE post_type = 'attachment' 
    AND post_parent IN 
        ( SELECT ID FROM 
            ( SELECT ID FROM wp_posts a 
                LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON (a.ID = b.post_id) 
                LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (a.ID = mt1.post_id) 
                WHERE post_type = 'product' AND mt1.meta_key = '_mycbgenie_managed_by' 
             ) AS taskstodelete 
        ) 
)
```

Comment: Does what you have work the way you want to? What´s the problem with it running for X seconds? Maybe that´s just the time it needs, depending on your set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cut the query in smaller parts, using temporary tables. Having sub queries is always time, memory and cpu consuming.
That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You make the same join twice! One is enough:

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN 
( SELECT ID FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'attachment' 
AND post_parent IN 
    ( SELECT ID FROM 
        ( SELECT ID FROM wp_posts a 
            LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (a.ID = mt1.post_id) 
            WHERE a.post_type = 'product' AND mt1.meta_key = '_mycbgenie_managed_by' 
         ) AS taskstodelete 
    ) 
)
```